# Find the smallest positive zero of the equation $ x = \tan x$.

Tags: matlab

Based on this question,

[image: screenshot of question]

Does it means I need to find the five smallest roots on the positive $x$ axis?

What interval would these roots lie on?

Comment: The question only asks you to find one positive solution of $x=\tan{x}$.

Comment: Question (a) asks about $x = \tan x$ (find smallest positive zero) and question (b) asks about a certain Bessel function you're given computer code for (find the 5 smallest zeros). There are lots of intervals these roots lie in, one of which is $(0,\infty),$ although I suspect a closer fitting interval is desired.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe some network problems make me can not open your website. This is a transcendental equation. I try to solve this problem by WolframAlpha, here is the answer 
https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=x%3Dtanx

I think it is not easy to find the specific roots. If you find some interesting ideas please let me know.